# Child component textbox default value not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a collection of questions and a textbox to get the answer. I want the textbox to have a blank default value every time I click the next button to get to the next one but it keeps having the value of the last answer I submitted. I've looked at changing state in the child component but that doesn't seem to do it and would appreciate any suggestions/ideas? Here is the code:

```
  // function is rendering each question one by one. 
  function generateQuestions() {

    return <Grid container spacing={3}>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <QuestionTile 
                  questionNumber={questionNumber}
                  question={currentQuestions[questionNumber].question}
                  answer={currentQuestions[questionNumber].answer}
                  updateUserAnswer={updateUserAnswers}
                  currentUserAnswer={" "}
                  // currentUserAnswers[questionNumber] === null ? " " : currentUserAnswers[questionNumber]
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                {getNextAndPrevButtons(currentQuestions.length)}
              </Grid>
            </Grid>;
  }
```

And the child component:

```
export default function QuestionTile({question, questionNumber, answer, updateUserAnswer, currentUserAnswer}) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [userAnswer, setUserAnswer] = useState(currentUserAnswer)

    function updateTextBoxValue(questionNumber, value) {

      console.log("Updating text box value")
      setUserAnswer(value)
      console.log(userAnswer)
      updateUserAnswer(questionNumber, value)
      setUserAnswer(currentUserAnswer)
    }


    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Grid container spacing={3} >
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Title>{questionNumber + 1}) {question}</Title>
              </Grid>
                <Title>Answer: </Title>
                <TextField
                  id={questionNumber}
                  defaultValue={currentUserAnswer}                
                  type="number"
                  className={classes.basicQuestionPadding}
                  onChange={(event) => updateTextBoxValue(questionNumber, event.target.value)}
                /> 
            </Grid>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

I am storing the user's answers as a list in the state of the parent component, this is the code for the function I'm passing to the child:

```
  function updateUserAnswers(questionNumber, answer) {
    currentUserAnswers[questionNumber] = answer
  }
```

For the sake of completeness, the code for the Submit and prev buttons is below:

```
 // Store the question number in state to trigger re-render on question change (and hence show new question)
  function getNextAndPrevButtons(numberOfQuestions) {
    if ((questionNumber < (numberOfQuestions-1)) && questionNumber >= 1) {
      return <Grid container direction="row"  spacing={10}>
        <Grid className={classes.QuestionNavButtons} justify="space-between" item xs={5}>
          <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => setQuestionNumber(questionNumber-1)}>Prev</Button>
        </Grid>
        {/* <Grid item xs={6}><div></div></Grid> */}
        <Grid className={classes.QuestionNavButtons} justify="space-between" item xs={5}>
          <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => setQuestionNumber(questionNumber+1)}>Submit</Button>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>;
    } 
   
    if (questionNumber >= 1) {
      return <Grid container direction="row"  spacing={10}>
      <Grid className={classes.QuestionNavButtons} justify="space-between" item xs={5}>
        <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => setQuestionNumber(questionNumber-1)}>Prev</Button>
      </Grid>
      <Grid className={classes.QuestionNavButtons} justify="space-between" item xs={5}>
        <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => setLevel("answers")}>View Answers</Button>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>;    
    }

    if (questionNumber < (numberOfQuestions-1)) {
      return <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => setQuestionNumber(questionNumber+1)}>Next</Button>;
    }
  }
```

This is my first time posting a question on stack overflow so please let me know if there are any details I'm missing.

Thanks!

Comment: code for the next button click?

Comment: @Apostolos have just added

Comment: im not sure if the defaultValue causes the problem. which lirary ar you using? react-bootstrap?

Comment: The library is Material-ui. I was thinking that react is only rendering certain parts of the dom in the child component which is why the actual question and question number change but for some reason this doesn't affect the TextField component. I am unable to force rerender the whole component successfully either.

Comment: not so familiar with this library to be honest

Comment: The TextField element I'm using from it is essentially an abstraction of the react input component and has all the same properties. Here is a link with more detail - https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/

Answer (score 1):

I was able to answer this by adding a key prop to the TextField element and made sure it was something that changed for each question. In this case the answer. This is **not** **optimal** as it misses the use case of two questions having the same answer(this would not trigger a re-render). Something better could be to pass down a counter or something. Its also probably not the cleanest solution either so still welcoming better ones in the meantime.